# How to create a voice channel by reacting on embed?

Tags: node.js, discord.js

I'm trying to use this code to create an embed, if you react on it a specific voice channel will be created on the server.
That's very similar to roles menu, but it will not give you a role, it will create a channel.

The code is working, but when you react on the embed the bot do nothing.

```js
module.exports = {
    name: 'cc',
    description: 'Help!',
    execute(message) {
    const embed = {"image": {"url": `${message.author.displayAvatarURL}`}}
    message.channel.send({embed})
    .then((message) => { message.react("❤") })
    .then(() => {
        const filter = (reaction, user) => reaction.emoji.name === "❤" && user.id === message.author.id;
        const collectorForU = message.createReactionCollector(filter, {time: 1000/*time in ms*/});
        collectorForU.on("collect", () => {message.guild.createChannel("╔═════ஜ۞ஜ═════╗", "voice")})
})  
}
};
```

There is no error on the console.

Comment: Your `time` option in the reaction collector is the equivalent to one second. Have you tried allowing more time?

Comment: oh yes, i found that too, its working now

Comment: but how to make it forever?

Comment: Give me an example pls, i really tried many things and i didn't find anything useful on docs :-(

Comment: You should create a new question for this, comments aren't the place.

Comment: ok, i will do that now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reaction collector expires before anything can be collected; the `time` option is set to 1 second.